# 415 error code is being thrown even after setting content type

Tags: postgresql, web-services, heroku, jersey, jax-rs

I have used the following code to create table:

```
CREATE TABLE   IF NOT EXISTS TRENDING (ID SERIAL   PRIMARY KEY , TOPIC TEXT , CATEGORY   TEXT ,QUESTION TEXT,ANSWER TEXT,PROFILEPIC TEXT NOT NULL,TICK TIMESTAMP,url TEXT);
```

I'm using the following code to accept a post request and insert the dates into postgres db.

```java
@POST
@Path("addTrending")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public static String addTrending(Trending trending){
    String songString = "requesting";
    ArrayList<Success> output = new ArrayList();

    try {

        Connection connection = MyResource.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement stmt = connection
        .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO TRENDING (TOPIC,CATEGORY,QUESTION,ANSWER,PROFILEPIC,TICK,URL) VALUES(?, ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? )");
        stmt.setString(1, trending.getTopic());
        stmt.setString(2, trending.getCategory());
        stmt.setString(3, trending.getQuestion());
        stmt.setString(4, trending.getAnswer());
        stmt.setString(5, trending.getProfilePic());
        stmt.setTimestamp(6, trending.getTimeStamp());
        stmt.setString(7, trending.getUrl());
        songString = "success";

    } catch(Exception ex){
        songString = "failure";
    }
    output.add(new Success(songString));

    return output.toString();
}
```

Following is the JSON request that I'm making:

```
{
  "timeStamp": "2016-10-11 14:11:52.516596",
  "question": "what?",
  "answer": "yes",
  "profilepic": "assa",
  "topic": "Paul",
  "id": 2,
  "category": "FIlter",
  "url": "a"   
}
```

I have used the consumes annotation properly. I have also set `application/json` as my content type but still im getting:

> HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type

How can I be able to sort this out?

Comment: But the class trending is not be able to parse the json

Comment: However If i pass a string as a parameter and if I try to convert the string to json objet and do the insert operation, Im able to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this dependecy

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
</dependency>
```